# CockroachDB: Why are deletes getting slower over time?

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm noticing my CockroachDB deletes getting slower over time. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From CockroachDB Docs:
CockroachDB relies on multi-version concurrency control (MVCC) to process concurrent requests while guaranteeing strong consistency. As such, when you delete a row, it is not immediately removed from disk. The MVCC values for the row will remain until the garbage collection period defined by the gc.ttlseconds variable in the applicable zone configuration has passed. By default, this period is 25 hours.

This means that with the default settings, each iteration of your DELETE statement must scan over all of the rows previously marked for deletion within the last 25 hours. If you try to delete 10,000 rows 10 times within the same 25 hour period, the 10th command will have to scan over the 90,000 rows previously marked for deletion.

To preserve performance over iterative DELETE queries, we recommend taking one of the following approaches:

At each iteration, update the WHERE clause to filter only the rows that have not yet been marked for deletion. For an example, see Batch-delete on an indexed filter above.
At each iteration, first use a SELECT statement to return primary key values on rows that are not yet deleted. Rows marked for deletion will not be returned. Then, use a nested DELETE loop over a smaller batch size, filtering on the primary key values. For an example, see Batch delete on a non-indexed column above.
To iteratively delete rows in constant time, using a simple DELETE loop, you can alter your zone configuration and change gc.ttlseconds to a low value like 5 minutes (i.e., 300), and then run your DELETE statement once per GC interval.

Comment: Hard to `DELETE` like a Cockroach is hard to kill

Answer (score 0):

Create index for `WHERE` section of your `DELETE` query:
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/indexes#best-practices

Read more:
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/delete#batch-delete-on-an-indexed-column